In django how can i do listing of the data which has been user forignkey key in this
In my Django project, I have implemented two models: one for the vendor and the other for the user. The user model serves as the main authentication model and has been configured with specific permissions. Additionally, the user model includes a foreign key referencing the vendor model, enabling users to log in with their own credentials in the Django admin interface.
Furthermore, users possess the permission to create entries in the User model. However, a challenge arises when attempting to assign a foreign key in the users model's company field, as it currently retrieves all available vendors. Instead, the objective is to retrieve only the vendor associated with the user
How i can i achive this?
i have tried with admin configs using this
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(auth_admin.UserAdmin):
    form = UserAdminChangeForm
    add_form = UserAdminCreationForm
    fieldsets = (
        (
            _("Personal info"),
            {"fields": ("username", "password", "name", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "role", "vendor")},
        ),
        (
            _("Permissions"),
            {
                "fields": (
                    "is_active",
                    "is_staff",
                    "is_superuser",
                    "groups",
                    "user_permissions",
                ),
            },
        ),
        (_("Important dates"), {"fields": ("last_login", "date_joined")}),
    )
    list_display = [
        "uuid",
        "username",
        "name",
        "email",
        "get_vendor_name",
        "role",
        "is_superuser",
        "is_active",
        "created",
    ]
    search_fields = ["name", "uuid", "email"]

    def get_vendor_name(self, obj):
        return obj.vendor.name if obj.vendor else None

    get_vendor_name.short_description = "Vendor Name"

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        # Save the current user for later use
        self.current_user = request.user
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "vendor" and not request.user.is_superuser:
            # Filter the queryset to only include the current user's company
            kwargs["queryset"] = Vendor.objects.filter(uuid=request.user.vendor.uuid)
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)


    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        # Get the current user's company
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            user = request.user.vendor # Assuming 'company' is the foreign key field in User model
            # Filter the queryset to only include the current user's company
            return super().get_queryset(request).filter(vendor=user)
        return queryset
    
    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
        """
        Determines the HttpResponse for the add_view stage.
        """
        # Customize the success message
        messages.success(request, _("The user %(name)s was added successfully.") % {'name': obj.username})

        # Determine where to redirect after the user has been added
        if "_continue" in request.POST:
            # If the user clicked "Save and continue editing", redirect to the change form for the new user
            post_url_continue = reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (obj._meta.app_label, obj._meta.model_name),
                                        args=(obj.pk,),
                                        current_app=self.admin_site.name)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(post_url_continue)
        elif "_addanother" in request.POST:
            # If the user clicked "Save and add another", redirect to the add form for a new user
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
        else:
            # If the user clicked "Save", redirect to the change list for users
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:%s_%s_changelist' % (obj._meta.app_label, obj._meta.model_name),
                                                current_app=self.admin_site.name))


